# How can I, a regular user, share files with specified users in Linux

Tags: linux, file-sharing

On a Linux (Ubuntu, although a non-distribution-specific solution is preferred) machine, I would like to give another user read and write access to some of my files.  Neither of us is an admin, so we can't create a group.  Can this be done?

Comment: Is this another user on the same machine?  Or a different machine on the same local network?  Or is the user somewhere across the Internet?

Comment: If you don't need a "real" bidirectional share, the recipient of the files can create a "drop box" folder with write-only permissions into which you can copy the files he wants to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if there is a "getfacl" command.

If there is such command you are able to use ACL's. It is extension of standard privilages system.
You are able then to run command:

```
setfacl -m u:username:rw filename
```

Comment: This does seem to be exactly what I want, although unfortunately it's not available on this system.

Answer (score 0):

Other than to rsync back and forth, I cannot think of a "good" solution. I'd recommend something like this:

- User A -> rsync -> $userB/userA
- User B -> rsync -> $userA/userB

Therefore you always have your copy. After that I'd "diff out" the files changed.

- User A -> find userB/ -atime...
- User B -> the reverse.

I wouldn't recommend giving immediate write permissions; I can imagine some file-locking issues.

I'd suggest a common NFS/FTP share somewhere else.